# Change predefined style inside a control in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, wpf-controls

I have the following style in App.xaml:

```
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">

            <Style.Resources>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="Unpressed">
                    <Image Stretch="Uniform"  Source="Img/button1.png"/>
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="Pressed">
                    <Image Stretch="Uniform" Source="Img/button1_press.png"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Style.Resources>

            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource Unpressed}"/>

            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource Pressed}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>

        </Style>
```

I want to change the data template from my button, something like this:

```
                    <Button x:Name="Button2">

                    <Style>
                        <Style.Resources>
                            <DataTemplate x:Key="Unpressed">
                                <Image Stretch="Uniform" Source="../Img/button2.png"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate x:Key="Pressed">
                                <Image Stretch="Uniform" Source="../Img/button2_press.png"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Style.Resources>
                    </Style>

                </Button>
```

So basically, all my buttons have the same style but each button have an unique image, I need to change the DataTemplate of the style individually for each button

Comment: If you set the style in the App.xaml Resources, and give it a key, you will be able to access it globally by using 'Style={StaticResource myStyle}' .

Comment: That's not the problem, all the buttons automatically gets the style, I want to change the DataTempalte with the icon path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my proposed solution:

For the style:

```
<Application.Resources>

    <local:ImgToDisplayConverter x:Key="ImgToDisplayConverter"/>
    <local:ImgPressedToDisplayConverter x:Key="ImgPressedToDisplayConverter"/>

    <Style TargetType="Image" x:Key="PressedButtonImageStyle">
        <Setter Property="Source">
            <Setter.Value>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ImgToDisplayConverter}">
                    <Binding Path="Tag" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsPressed, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}}" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Source">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ImgPressedToDisplayConverter}">
                            <Binding Path="Tag" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

</Application.Resources>
```

For the Control:

```
    <Button Tag="button1"  Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <ContentControl>
            <Image Stretch="Uniform" Style="{StaticResource PressedButtonImageStyle}" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
        </ContentControl>
    </Button>
```

The Converters:

```
 class ImgToDisplayConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string image = values[0].ToString();
        string resourceName = String.Format("pack://application:,,,/{0}.png", image);

        return new BitmapImage(new Uri(resourceName));
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

class ImgPressedToDisplayConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string image = values[0].ToString();
        string resourceName = String.Format("pack://application:,,,/{0}_pressed.png", image);

        return new BitmapImage(new Uri(resourceName));
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You can change the code depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I use this simple code and it works well(if you want to release the button from being pressed ,set timer).I hope this will help you..

> xaml code

```xml
<Button Name="male" Height="318" Width="352" Click="male_Click" Margin="236,120,1332,642">
    <Button.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="pack://application:,,,/Imagesrc/logotype/USER_MALE.png" ></ImageBrush>
    </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

> pressed code

```cs
public void male_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Controls.Image img = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
    img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/maindocket;component/Imagesrc/logotype/USER_MALE_SELECTED.png"));
    male.Content = img;
}
```